# CentOS 7 - Not Getting IP Address After Reboot

Tags: centos, centos7

I can't quite seem to figure out why. Seems very odd.

Setup;

- DHCP/Static IP Managed on Router/Firewall
- VM with CentOS 7 Installed that ultimately gets IP address from above

Seems that whenever I reboot the VM, I have to run the command `dhclient` for the VM to pick up the IP address and start working.

What gives? Usually this stuff just works out of the box, not sure what is going on here.

For added context, I've got the CentOS 7 VM configured as DHCP, and on the firewall it's configured for MAC ID XYZ = Static IP 1.2.3.4 so that I can keep the management of this simple. I don't want to go having to manage static IPs at the VM level as the VM should just accept whatever IP it is given from DHCP/Static as appropriate.

Feels like I'm missing something blindingly obvious here that is getting in the way of basic behaviour.

**Update**
Turns out that the default when installing Cent OS 7 and configuring the network on the installation screen is that this results in the default line in the file, **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0** is

```
ONBOOT=no
```

So I just changed that and it's working now as expected. Odd for CentOS 7 to default to not connecting to a network automatically on boot.

Comment: How have you configured networking on your CentOS VM? That would normally mean `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interfacename>`. What do you have there, what does it look like, and does it match your actual network device name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your interface config file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX
Make sure config is similar to below.

```
DEVICE=ethX
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```

I Guess `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` might be missing.

Please feel free to update question if doesn't work